# Golang Listener and Dialer

Tags: http, go

I am having difficulty connecting my program to my local host. After doing some debugging I found that my problem is my listener and dialer. They aren't "talking". Could someone assist me in figuring out the problem.

**client**

```
 func NewServer(httpAddr string , remoteAddr string , webdirect string, cacheInterval time.Duration) (*Server, error) {

    conn, err := grpc.DialContext( context.Background(),"localhost:8080",    grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock())

       if err != nil {

          //return nil, err
          log.Fatalf("Unable to connect to server: %v", err)
       }

     defer conn.Close()

// make a grpc pb client
client := pb.NewClicksClient(conn)

return &APIServer{
    grpcConn:    conn,
    clicks: client,
    webdirect:      webdirect,
    httpAddr:    httpAddr,
    cache: Cache{
        loop: sync2.NewCycle(cacheInterval),
    },
}, nil
}
```

**server**

```
func Start(ctx context.Context, remoteAddr string) error {

  lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost: 8080")
      if err != nil {
         log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
         }

  clicks := &ClicksDatabase{}

   s := grpc.NewServer()

   pb.RegisterClicksServer(s, clicks)

   log.Println("Serving gRPC on 0.0.0.0:8080")

        if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}

return s.Serve(lis)

}
```

Comment: When you "start", do you run the server in a new goroutine?

Comment: There's a space between your host & port  `localhost: 8080`

Comment: @hasen thank you! Using a new groutine (opening it in a new terminal) worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `localhost: 8080` with just `:8080` in your `net.Listen`